# Restore Backup of Magento 2 on AWS Stack

Tags: magento2, backup, aws

Deployed Magento 2 site on AWS using AWS CloudFormation Template.

We have a backup of the running site of Magento 2 which is currently running on a single VM (MySQL and Webserver).
while trying to restore the backup from running site to new AWS Stack, it shows "The rollback file is invalid. Verify the file and try again."

I have copied the backup into /var/www/html/var/backups

Do I need to register it somewhere for Magento to identify it as a Magento backup?

Found a difference of backup filename prefix as below,

-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx    878119 Apr  9 08:11 1586419820_db.sql
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nginx nginx  48366101 Apr  9 08:12 1586419915_media_Test.tgz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nginx nginx 139980273 Apr  9 09:01 1586350293_media_backup.tgz

15864 is the backups generated from magento admin console (AWS), 15863 is from our running Magento.

Please help!!!

[image]

Comment: do not use magento to backup or roll back

Answer (score 0):

> Deprecation Notice: Magento backup functionality is deprecated as of
>   2.1.16, 2.2.7, and 2.3.0. We recommend investigating additional backup technologies and binary backup tools (such as Percona XtraBackup).

please never use magento itself to backup.

use: tar, rsync, S3cmd, deploy tools, github, mysqldump, or percona toolkit